# Elasticsearch - Filter by sum of multiple fields greater than a specific value

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{ "name": "tom", "attempt1": 30, "attempt2": 30, "attempt3": 40 }
{ "name": "jerry", "attempt1": 20, "attempt2": 10, "attempt3": 20 }
{ "name": "cat", "attempt1": 80, "attempt2": 90, "attempt3": 10 }
{ "name": "mouse", "attempt1": 30, "attempt2": 30, "attempt3": 30 }
```

I want to filter docs with (attempt1 + attempt2 + attempt3) > 99

Expected result

```
{ "name": "tom", "attempt1": 30, "attempt2": 30, "attempt3": 40 }
{ "name": "cat", "attempt1": 80, "attempt2": 90, "attempt3": 10 }
```

Any way to do this in elastic search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach would be to use a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) like this:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['attempt1'].value + doc['attempt2'].value + doc['attempt3'].value > params.threshold",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params": {
                          "threshold": 99
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If running the query above on a big number of documents, make sure to add as many constraints as possible to reduce the set of documents the script will need to run on.

The right way to do it is to pre-compute the sum and index it in another field so that you can use a [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) on that new field. Depending on the number of documents you have, it would be much more optimal.

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly @Val. I tried function_score, think was doing the wrong way. This is much simpler and works.